# Is Classic mode gone from 11.10?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I am trying to turn off unity (or see if you can go back to a Classic Ubuntu desktop) in 11.10. So far, I can not find a way to turn it off.

There is a regular, and 2D option at login time, and that's it. Both options take you to a Unity desktop.

Answer (score 2):

The classic GNOME desktop is gone, but it can be downloaded