# How do I find "system > preferences"?

Tags: system, preferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find administration, preferences, etc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66527/where-to-find-administration-preferences-etc)

Many Ubuntu instructions start with "System > Preferences". On Ubuntu 10 there was a System menu in the upper left corner of the UI. On 11 there is no such menu. What to do?

Answer (score 5):

Click on de power icon in the upper right corner of your screen, there you will find system preferences.

Answer (score 0):

It is in the launcher, near the bottom "System Settings"

If it helps, there are several guides to Unity, this one is popular

http://omgubuntu.co.uk/natty/