# Where is "System" OR "Preferences"?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find administration, preferences, etc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66527/where-to-find-administration-preferences-etc)

I have been staring at the same screen trying to find the System button or Preferences. I was reading an article on how to find the System button, and it said it's under Preferences. Now where is Preferences? I can't even find that!